# Angular only works if I specify app.get("*"[...]); in my server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I just startet developing with server side JavaScript and this is my first project with it.

It is a command and control server for my owncloud server running with angular, Expressjs and bootstrap. At the moment I got trouble adding the functionality for the stop server button.

It should some code to log into the the server via `ssh` and do all the necessary stuff to shut it down gracefully.

The problem is, that I really can't (and also don't want to) add this via a browser script since I want to use an ssh library. Running a server side script by pressing a button doesn't seem to be possible at all (please tell me how if it is anyway, that would be the solution to all of my problems :)).

So I thought I could redirect the user to the `/on` page as he clicks the button and perform the actions in the app.get callback function. And here is the problem: In my `server.js` (the main node server) I have "two" endpoints defined at the moment

```
app.get("*", (req, res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "src/index.html"));
});
```

and

```
app.get("/on", (req, res) =>{
  console.log("redirecting...");
  //DO SOMETHING
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

In the second one I would like to perform the ssh actions.
But as I change the first code block to (notice the / instead of the *)

```
app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "src/index.html"));
});
```

The whole app doesn't seem to have angular any more. All angular components do show up but they are just empty and not filled with the content I defined in the app.component.html. Why is this occurring and how can I fix this? Thank you for any help ;)
PS: you can find all the code at: [GitHub](https://github.com/Clemens-Dautermann/node-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you would preferably do, but to keep the answer short, you need few changes so you can have this up and running, first, `app.get("*", ...)` redirects every get to that code block, so you need to do this:

```
//Parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));


app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));
});

app.get("/on", (req, res) =>{
  console.log("redirecting...");
  //DO SOMETHING
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

Notice one change, you don't want to call the src/index, you want to build the angular to dist folder and use that index.html, second, the route "/" will redirect to home page, the "/on" will now enter the the desired endpoint. If this is pretty much everything you want to do with the endpoints, i guess this is fine, but if you want to build something more complex, i would abstract things out. hope this helps, cheers.
[image: breakpoint was on line 21 and it entered as soon as i did the localhost:3000/on]

Comment: Doesn't work as well... (same result). There are also no files in the dist folder that seem have to do anything with the app.component

Comment: Thats weird, i just cloned your repo, installed, made those changes and everything worked(i debugged and got into my breakpoint).

Comment: The app.component you wont see in dist folder, when you do ng build --aot --prod it will compile typescript into javascript and you will see just few bundled (preferably) minified javascript files that contains all code you wrote. i will post the picture to my answer with all the changes i did to your project on github...

Comment: when you do those changes, you do npm run-script build(ng build --aot --prod), and then simply do node server.js from the root folder

Comment: Works perfectly! I just used ng build without --aot and --prod. With those it works (although I have no Idea what they do but thats just one google query). Thank You!:)

Comment: Anytime brother